# How to Implement chat application for Android?

Tags: android, web-services, chat

I am working on a chat application for android. This chat application is for sending messages from one device to another using internet(GPRS,3G,etc) from this application. please tell me a way to implement this.

I thought using web services is more data(internet) consuming and less efficient.is this right?

I worked on server and client sockets. I ran both server and client classes in single device and messages can be transfered from client socket to server socket and vice versa.Now i want to message between two devices using server socket on web server and how to connect to server from Android Devices.

Answer (score 3):

[This](http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/comment-page-4/#comment-3016) helps you to solve Push Notification in Android Chat applications. You may also build your own push notification server backed by the [Really Small Message Broker](http://u7572305.fsdata.se/rsmb/doc/gettingstarted.htm#installing)(a small program that sends and receives data in the form of messages to and from applications and devices over TCP/IP network connections.)

Comment: Yadav Ji, Is there are any perfect example to implement push notification(server side and client side also)

Comment: @AshishDwivedi, its the fact, that, lack of native Push on Android seems like a huge drawback. thanks to Apple, BlackBerry. `Persistent TCP/IP` is probably the best way to go until Google actually takes the matter in their own hands. After all, that’s how GMail, GTalk and Google Voice implement their real-time updates. After googling a  lot i found `above links`, that show perfect way to implement push notification. @thanks to Anton & IBM.

Comment: @Yadav Ji: Link is dead

Comment: [Google Cloud Messaging for Android](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) will help you out for push notification. [push-notifications-using google GCM](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/) is one of the best example to start with GCM.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Xtify](http://www.xtify.com/) push notification service to implement the chat feature. It is much easier to use with their provided sample code and all.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this...[quickblox](http://quickblox.com/developers/SuperSample_%28Map_Chat_code_sample%29_Android) will be easier enough to implement server based applications. As in your case you needs interaction with the server to built a chatting application in Android.