# Android chat functionality?

Tags: android, chat

I am trying to implement simple chat application for android. The concept is, users have to register and login to their account and can chat with each other. And i implemented the server side logic for registration kind of thing.

Can anyone please tell me the simplest and the most efficient way to design a chat application...

Please do the needful.

Thanks,
Sai

Answer (score 3):

Simplest and efficient solution is to use a chat sdk. There are plenty of chat as a service solution available which provides the chat sdk along with backend. Have a look at https://www.applozic.com/docs/android-chat-sdk.html

Github Android SDK: https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK

Below tutorial will be of help:
https://dzone.com/articles/add-chat-using-applozic-in-5-mins

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Google Talk API to build an XMPP client. That way, registration &c. are handled for you; you don't have to worry about maintaining a user database, connectivity, uptime, and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

You can use xmpp protocol for simple chat application which is supported by smack api.

[Please look at the  link. **OUTDATED SAMPLE**](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2007/12/31/android-just-use-smack-api-for-xmpp/)

**UPDATE** :

[Updated code of above tutorial is here](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/)

Answer (score 1):

Sai, The simplest way to make chat application is to make through web services. 
If want to make using web services then let me know,i will guide you step by step.

Comment: can you guide me i want to implement chat in android through services???? i really need it

Comment: Can you provide helpful data for implmenting chat using webservices.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking forward to implement chat functionality in your application, maybe [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203883/how-to-implement-chat-application-for-android/9954308#comment12795847_9954308) can help you.

Answer (score -1):

you can build your own chat app with opentalkon chat api https://github.com/OpenTalkOn/OpenTalkOn-Android-Chat-API

opentalkon api is very simple.

- Message Send
  You can easily send message with doSendMessage(TADataHandler handler, Long room_id, String msg, Long transact_id) method.
- Message Receive
  You can easily register handler for receiving message with setClientInterfaceMsgHandler (MessageHandler handler) method.

I recommend to use opentalkon api!