# Android chat and web.API

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc, chat

I have asp.net mvc application where's implemented web API 2. Now I'd like to make chat with my android application. I don't know how do it. Maybe exist libraries where's show it.

Comment: Unfortunately asking for libraries is off topic for Stackoverflow. Please try searching elsewhere for communication between Android and web services

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203883/how-to-implement-chat-application-for-android

Comment: I think you should to use push notificatons.